# Has anybody used PPCG.SE before April 5th?

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-bydesign

I'm serious. Does anybody here remember viewing *any pages* on PPCG.SE before the fifth of this month?

Because according to [the site analytics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (5k+ only), the only time anybody has *ever* visited or viewed pages on this site was between April 5th and April 10th, 2018.

[image: Hmm]

This is rather strange, because the other graphs (such as posts and votes) seem to be quite active. Could it be that everyone has actually just been using Stack Exchange API calls to browse PPCG without realizing it?

---

In seriousness, I have no idea what's happening here. Can anybody repro this? Is this happening on any other sites? (I don't have enough reputation to access site analytics on any other site.)

Comment: [This is a known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/307833). SE devs are working on a fix.

Comment: April Fools! They implanted memories of our use of the site in order to get us to use their brand new site with fabricated content.

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't really care if it's fabricated. It's content all the same...

Comment: @mbomb007 do they happen to have the source code?  I'd love a challenge fabricator.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Jon Skeet wrote them all.

Answer (score 8):

Due to [a whole lot of chaos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51) with our Google Analytics account, we kinda lost access to all information prior to April.

But, traffic *since then* should show up just fine now. That was fixed a couple months back; see the meta post linked above for details.